# Update elements in torch.zeros with other given tensors

Tags: pytorch

Let’s say, there are a PyTorch torch.zeros tensor (x-dim) and two other tensors 1-dim.

```
test_t = torch.zeros(2, 1, 1, 1)

output:
tensor([[[[0.]]],


        [[[0.]]]])
```

```
t1 = torch.tensor(10.)
t2 = torch.tensor(20.)
```

I want to modify the original tensor in-place and replace zeros with values in given order.

Required result:

```
test_t

output:
tensor([[[[10.]]],


        [[[20.]]]])
```

upd: see solution below

Comment: In general, yes!

Answer (score 0):

I got a hin from the Community - see comments.

```
answer:
test_t[0, 0, 0, :] = torch.tensor([10.])
test_t[1, 0, 0, :] = torch.tensor([20.])
```

```
test_t, test_t.shape

output:
(tensor([[[[10.]]],
 
 
         [[[20.]]]]),
 torch.Size([2, 1, 1, 1]))
```